# Laravel, Check if name of user exist on original laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent, frameworks

I have laravel application! I use original laravel authentication from

> php artisan make:auth

My question is how to check if name already exist in database and if exist to return error message!

My user table structure is:-

```
user: 
 id - UNIQUE 
 name 
 email  
 password  
 remembertoken  
 timestamps
```

Comment: User::where("name", $nameToTestAgainst)->first(); 
if it returns anything, then it exists, right?

Comment: Yeah but i want to when user type data in registration form to check in default Laravel RegisterController if name exist! I tried this way but return error ! :)

Comment: The questions needs to be more detailed in that case... anyway... if you want to validate the inputs, then use the laravel validator ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Laravel form validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

Following is quoted from there:

Use the "unique" rule for name.

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|unique:users'
]);
```

And display error like this:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div> @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**You actually have two solutions:**

1. Make sure you have an unique constraint on your database for name
2. See the code below

   ```
   $user = User::where("name", $nameToTestAgainst)->first();

   if($user!= null) {
       $v->errors()->add('Duplicate', 'Duplicate user found!');
       return redirect('to-your-view')
                      ->withErrors($v)
                      ->withInput();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use auth()->user()->name in blade file.

```
<?php $name=auth()->user()->name; ?>
```